# Creating an if, else statement for answers accordingly to the self.questions list

Tags: python, tkinter

How do I create these if and else statements from the `self.questions` list? What I am trying to do right now is that when the program is run, there are three option boxes with answers in each one.

I want the user to select one of those answers and see if they are correct or not according to the answers in the `self.questions` list corresponding to the asked question.

```
def __init__(self):
      self.newWindow = self.new_window('QUESTION')
      self.window = self.newWindow

      #This is a counter for the questions
      self.question_counter = 0

      #This is the questions, there is a list of questions
      self.questions = ["Question One: What is the capital of France?", "Question Two: What martial arts movie was first produced by Hollywood?",
                    "Question Three: What year did World War II start?", "Question Four: What year did Abraham Licoln get assassinated?"]                
      #This is the answers, there is a list of three possible answers for each question
      self.answers = [["Madrid", "London", "Paris"],
                  ["The Karate Kid", "Enter the Dragon", "Ip Man"],
                  ["1914", "1939", "1940"],
                  ["1865", "1912", "1688"]]

      self.label = Label(self.newWindow, 
      text=self.questions[self.question_counter], font = ("Arial", "24"), pady=30)

      self.answer1button = Button(self.window, text=self.answers[self.question_counter][0])
      self.answer2button = Button(self.window, text=self.answers[self.question_counter][1])
      self.answer3button = Button(self.window, text=self.answers[self.question_counter][2])
```

Comment: Please consider adding a code sample, or revising the one you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. Good luck with your code!

Answer (score 0):

you can create three methods inside the class, each corresponding to an answer/button. inside of the function check if the answer that was chosen is right and then if it is, add one to the questions counter and display the next question. then make each of the buttons execute the function related to them.